# Why Nginx calls for invalid certificate in non-existent subdomains just to redirect to 404?

Tags: nginx, ssl, configuration, https, http-status-code-404

1. Have two server blocks.
2. `default_server` block inside `http` block of `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
   server_name _;
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
   listen 443 default_server;
   return 404;
}
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

3. A working domain/website block inside `sites-enabled`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /var/www/example.com/htdocs/;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name www.example.com;
}
```

(I have this setup to redirect all non-www to www and all http to https)

4. I have a cert for both non-www and www for my domain. Nginx for some reason is calling any subdomain instead of giving default website cannot be found/`ERR_CONNECTION_RESET/` error.
5. For example if I go to `https://asdf.example.com/` Nginx calls it and browser tells you it's insecure SSL cert, then you accept it anyway and get a 404 page.
6. How do I jump to 404 page skipping the invalid cert message or how do I jump straight to 'page not found' and not the 404? E.g. like go to `https://asdf.serverfault.com` it doesn't give a 404, it gives a `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET/`. I want that for all non-existent subdomains and domains on my server.

**update:** Could it be that all my `ssl_certificate` lines are added to main http block too? If so, still doesn't solve calling for `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` and not 404 like given example on `6.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open https://asdf.example.com directly then browser will resolve `asdf.example.com` to an IP address and then connect to it using `HTTPS` protocol. If server (with retrieved IP) is listening on `443` port and returns no certificate for this domain, or an invalid one than browser will warn you about insecure protocol before finishing up the request (e.g. displaying `404` error).

https://asdf.serverfault.com gives an connection error because this subdomain is not registered, it has no IP address. That's why you see this error. If you want to make sure `asdf.example.com` returns an connection error instead of ssl warning then make sure that this subdomain is not registered and there is no wildcard (*) record for `example.com`.

Comment: You mean no CNAME with wildcard for example.com in the DNS records?

Comment: `https://asdf.serverfault.com` does not give a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET since there is no connection which could have been resetted.  As you correctly said the site has no entry in DNS and thus the client fails to determine an IP address for the site which means that it cannot create a TCP connection to it. But ERR_CONNECTION_RESET is the result of receiving a RST packet on an established TCP connection, which does not exist in this case.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Chrome reports ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. Also if server didn't listen to 443 then how would SSL work, I'm not following. You're suggesting to remove `listen 443 default_server;`?

Comment: My chrome reports DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. Chrome might report ERR_CONNECTION_RESET if you connect through a proxy and only the proxy tries to resolve the domain name. In this case there is a TCP connection to the proxy which can be resetted.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You are right, it is not `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in this case.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You're right, my Chrome was on proxy.

Comment: @user3108268 No, i mean both `A` and `CNAME`

Comment: @Paweł Tatarczuk I already didn't have an `A` record and removing the wildcard `CNAME` fixed it, all of it. Didn't do anything the 443 port part, so not sure if need to change anything about it.

Comment: I've changed my answer so it does not mislead that missing DNS entry ends with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` thanks to @SteffenUllrich comment.

Comment: @user3108268 Nginx config seems fine. I don't think there is any way to prevent ssl warning on domains pointing to server with nginx listening to `443` port which does not have a valid ceritifacte for that domain.